# Make multiple versions of program show up in "Open With" dialog in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I have multiple versions of MATLAB installed (e.g. R2010b, R2012a, R2013b,...), and when I open a MATLAB file from the microsoft file explorer I want to be able to choose which version of MATLAB to open it in. On my Windows 7 Pro laptop when I right-click on a MATLAB file, go to Open With, I see all of my installed MATLAB versions, and can choose the appropriate one as desired. However, on a Windows 7 Ultimate machine I remote desktop into, when I right click on a MATLAB file, and bring up the "Open With" dialog box, it only shows one version, R2013b. If I click "Browse" in the "Open With" dialog box and choose C:/Program Files/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/matlab.exe, it does nothing - it still only shows R2013b in the list of available programs to open the file with. I can just open the file from within MATLAB, but I want to know how I can get Windows to show all of my installed versions from file explorer?

I have admin privileges on both machines.

Answer (score 0):

[This Technet Article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/6452.how-to-configure-an-open-with-preference-group-policy-item.aspx) talks you through the process you require.  You should be able to create multiple "open with" associations for your desired file types.

I have quickly (successfully) tested this for a made up file extension which i created by renaming a notepad doc and it wioked fine for me.

Comment: Thanks, this is getting me closer. However, that article is for Windows-XP, and I am having trouble finding the same options in Windows-7. Could you give directions for finding the New Open With Properties dialog box? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry.. should have realised it was win 7... these instructions strangely work on my 8.1 and xp boxes.. but not 7?!  Anyhow, here's some instructions: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/take-control-of-your-windows-7-open-with-menus